# Crystal Reports Viewer Flash Support after 2020

Tags: java, eclipse, web, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I'm working on a website that has integrated years ago the Crystal Report Viewer 12 for JAVA (JSP) on my website. However, When I need to run a report on Google Chrome, I'm receiving the following message:

> "Flash Player will no longer be supported after December 2020"

I have research and I found the SAP [Crystal Reports Viewer 2016](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-29757), and according to documentation, it seems it will no longer require Flash Player, and it uses HTML5 power instead.
I'm not really sure about how to proceed, but I have changed the old *.jar libraries with the newly downloaded ones:

```
com.azalea.ufl.barcode.1.0.jar
CrystalCommon2.jar
CrystalReportsRuntime.jar
cvom.jar
DatabaseConnectors.jar
icu4j.jar
jai_imageio.jar
JDBInterface.jar
jrcerom.jar
keycodeDecoder.jar
logging.jar
pfjgraphics.jar
QueryBuilder.jar
webreporting-jsf.jar
webreporting.jar
XMLConnector.jar
xpp3.jar
```

However, the report viewer still asking for Flash to be installed.
I have been searching for a full JAVA library because, from the resource, I can only find the *.jar files, but not the full version as it's implemented in the web server, which includes the css, html, images and js libraries.

My questions:

1. Is there really a Crystal Report Viewer free of the Flash Player dependency for JRC Java?
2. Maybe, The report itself is the one with the Flash Player dependency, but the report viewer is fine by just updating the libraries as I did?

I'm publishing here because seems that SAP Crystal Reports docs are very deprecated :S
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the right library in the following link: [Crystal Reports for Eclipse SP25 Runtime Libraries](https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html)

As it is described in the following source: [What's new in SP 25 to be updated](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/SAP+Crystal+Reports+version+for+Eclipse+-+Downloads)
They have implemented an

> UI5 parameter and DB logon prompt that no longer depends on Flash

I have implemented it on my website, and it's no longer asking for Flash player to be installed (great!), however, Take into account that the cache must be completely deleted in order to the new HTML5 based prompts loads properly.

Comment: did you add any code after updating the library ? and can you specify which library have you replaced ? or you just put the whole new kit !
I replaced the libraries but still looking for flash to display the prompt :/ thanx

Comment: I replaced everything except the custom and config files. take into account that cache must be refreshed, and the new .jar files to be used

Comment: it's now displaying the new prompt but when I set the param value and execute, it refreshs the whole page and it displays again the prompt, did this happen to you or not ? thanks